# Parking rules in associations

Tags: civil-legal-system

I live in a condo association, i have 2 parking spaces that came assigned with the property, im an owner. if I want a friend, neighbor, anyone to park in any of my parking spaces, lets say because im not at home and I just let a friend to park in there while Im working, can security remove the car from my parking space?

Answer (score 3):

Very likely. You may own your parking space, but when you bought your condo you also signed a contract agreeing to abide by the rules of the condo association.

Condo associations typically have rules that all cars parked on the property must be registered with the association. If you didn't register your friend's car with the association, they have no way of known that it isn't some random person trespassing to score free parking. Some associations may have additional rules limiting parking to residents of the building.

Get in touch with your association and find out what the rules are. You should have been given a copy of the association rules when you closed on the purchase of the condo.